# How to fetch all API data using Gson volley in android

Tags: android, android-studio, gson, android-volley, android-recyclerview

> Have a look at my API data:

```
 {
            "items": [
        {
                    "id": 2,
                    "sku": "Beige and blue jacquard and chiffon embroidered saree & Blouse",
                    "name": "Beige and blue jacquard and chiffon embroidered saree & Blouse",
                    "attribute_set_id": 4,
                    "price": 25.5,
                    "status": 1,
                    "visibility": 4,
                    "type_id": "simple",
                    "created_at": "2018-04-25 08:52:58",
                    "updated_at": "2018-05-23 19:00:20",
                    "product_links": [],
                    "tier_prices": [],
                    "custom_attributes": [

                        {
                            "attribute_code": "image",
                            "value": "/6/7/6759_original_1.jpg"
                        },
                       {
                        "attribute_code": "category_ids",
                        "value": [
                            "5",
                            "13"
                        ]
                    }
                    ]
                }
        ],
            "search_criteria": {
                "filter_groups": []
            },
            "total_count": 574
        }
```

And my Model look like this:

```
-----------------------------------com.example
```

.apidata.models.CustomAttribute.java-----------------------------------

```
package com.example.apidata.models;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class CustomAttribute {

@SerializedName("attribute_code")
@Expose
private String attributeCode;
@SerializedName("value")
@Expose
private String value;

/**
* No args constructor for use in serialization
* 
*/
public CustomAttribute() {
}

/**
* 
* @param attributeCode
* @param value
*/
public CustomAttribute(String attributeCode, String value) {
super();
this.attributeCode = attributeCode;
this.value = value;
}

public String getAttributeCode() {
return attributeCode;
}

public void setAttributeCode(String attributeCode) {
this.attributeCode = attributeCode;
}

public String getValue() {
return value;
}

public void setValue(String value) {
this.value = value;
}

}
-----------------------------------com.example.apidata.models.Item.java-----------------------------------

package com.example.apidata.models;

public class Item {

@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private Integer id;
@SerializedName("sku")
@Expose
private String sku;
@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
private String name;
@SerializedName("attribute_set_id")
@Expose
private Integer attributeSetId;
@SerializedName("price")
@Expose
private float price;
@SerializedName("status")
@Expose
private Integer status;
@SerializedName("visibility")
@Expose
private Integer visibility;
@SerializedName("type_id")
@Expose
private String typeId;
@SerializedName("created_at")
@Expose
private String createdAt;
@SerializedName("updated_at")
@Expose
private String updatedAt;
@SerializedName("product_links")
@Expose
private List<Object> productLinks = null;
@SerializedName("tier_prices")
@Expose
private List<Object> tierPrices = null;
@SerializedName("custom_attributes")
@Expose
private List<Object> customAttributes = null;

/**
 * No args constructor for use in serialization
 *
 */
public Item() {
}

/**
 *
 * @param productLinks
 * @param updatedAt
 * @param id
 * @param price
 * @param attributeSetId
 * @param visibility
 * @param status
 * @param createdAt
 * @param name
 * @param tierPrices
 * @param sku
 * @param typeId
 * @param customAttributes
 */
public Item(Integer id, String sku, String name, Integer attributeSetId, Integer price, Integer status, Integer visibility, String typeId, String createdAt, String updatedAt, List<Object> productLinks, List<Object> tierPrices, List<Object> customAttributes) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.sku = sku;
    this.name = name;
    this.attributeSetId = attributeSetId;
    this.price = price;
    this.status = status;
    this.visibility = visibility;
    this.typeId = typeId;
    this.createdAt = createdAt;
    this.updatedAt = updatedAt;
    this.productLinks = productLinks;
    this.tierPrices = tierPrices;
    this.customAttributes = customAttributes;
}

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getSku() {
    return sku;
}

public void setSku(String sku) {
    this.sku = sku;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Integer getAttributeSetId() {
    return attributeSetId;
}

public void setAttributeSetId(Integer attributeSetId) {
    this.attributeSetId = attributeSetId;
}

public float getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public void setPrice(float price) {
    this.price = price;
}

public Integer getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(Integer status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public Integer getVisibility() {
    return visibility;
}

public void setVisibility(Integer visibility) {
    this.visibility = visibility;
}

public String getTypeId() {
    return typeId;
}

public void setTypeId(String typeId) {
    this.typeId = typeId;
}

public String getCreatedAt() {
    return createdAt;
}

public void setCreatedAt(String createdAt) {
    this.createdAt = createdAt;
}

public String getUpdatedAt() {
    return updatedAt;
}

public void setUpdatedAt(String updatedAt) {
    this.updatedAt = updatedAt;
}

public List<Object> getProductLinks() {
    return productLinks;
}

public void setProductLinks(List<Object> productLinks) {
    this.productLinks = productLinks;
}

public List<Object> getTierPrices() {
    return tierPrices;
}

public void setTierPrices(List<Object> tierPrices) {
    this.tierPrices = tierPrices;
}

public List<Object> getCustomAttributes() {
    return customAttributes;
}

public void setCustomAttributes(List<Object> customAttributes) {
    this.customAttributes = customAttributes;
}
```

}
    -----------------------------------com.example.apidata.models.Result.java-----------------------------------

```
package com.example.apidata.models;

import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Result {

@SerializedName("items")
@Expose
private List<Item> items = null;
@SerializedName("search_criteria")
@Expose
private SearchCriteria searchCriteria;
@SerializedName("total_count")
@Expose
private Integer totalCount;

/**
* No args constructor for use in serialization
* 
*/
public Result() {
}

/**
* 
* @param totalCount
* @param searchCriteria
* @param items
*/
public Result(List<Item> items, SearchCriteria searchCriteria, Integer totalCount) {
super();
this.items = items;
this.searchCriteria = searchCriteria;
this.totalCount = totalCount;
}

public List<Item> getItems() {
return items;
}

public void setItems(List<Item> items) {
this.items = items;
}

public SearchCriteria getSearchCriteria() {
return searchCriteria;
}

public void setSearchCriteria(SearchCriteria searchCriteria) {
this.searchCriteria = searchCriteria;
}

public Integer getTotalCount() {
return totalCount;
}

public void setTotalCount(Integer totalCount) {
this.totalCount = totalCount;
}

}
-----------------------------------com.example.apidata.models.SearchCriteria.java-----------------------------------

package com.example.apidata.models;

import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class SearchCriteria {

@SerializedName("filter_groups")
@Expose
private List<Object> filterGroups = null;

/**
* No args constructor for use in serialization
* 
*/
public SearchCriteria() {
}

/**
* 
* @param filterGroups
*/
public SearchCriteria(List<Object> filterGroups) {
super();
this.filterGroups = filterGroups;
}

public List<Object> getFilterGroups() {
return filterGroups;
}

public void setFilterGroups(List<Object> filterGroups) {
this.filterGroups = filterGroups;
}

}
```

I am fetching data in recycler view using Adapter but it gives error as :

> com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 408 path
>   $.items[0].custom_attributes[0].value

It gives me  value of array of "**items**", but it does not give values of array of "**custom_attributes**" array which is actually inside array of "**items**"

Here is my Adapter class:

```
public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter{

    private Context context;
    private List<Item> data = Collections.emptyList();
    public Adapter(List<Item> data)
    {
        this.data = data;

    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.grid,parent,false);
        return new ProgrammingViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

      final Item result = data.get(position);

      ((ProgrammingViewHolder)holder).name.setText(result.getName());
        ((ProgrammingViewHolder)holder).price.setText((int) result.getPrice());
((ProgrammingViewHolder)holder).image.setText(result.getCustomAttributes().toArray(););



    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    public class ProgrammingViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView name, price;
        ImageView image;

        public ProgrammingViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            price = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        }
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java:**

```
 RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);

        stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL_DATA, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.d("response", response);

                results = gson.fromJson(response, Result.class);


                data = results.getItems();
                Log.d("data", String.valueOf(data));

              adapter  =  new Adapter(data);
               programming_list.setAdapter(adapter);



            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            }) {
                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                    HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
                    headers.put("Authorization",  "API KEY");
                    return headers;
                }
        };

        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

So, please help me to fetch value of array "**custom_attributes**"

Comment: custom_attributes is List.you can get value items.get(POSITION).getCustom_attributes.get(POSITION).getAttribute_code();

Comment: Your actual issue is in Result.class-->Item.Class its one line fix... Can you please post your Result.class & Item.Class? so i can tell you where you have to change your code inside it

Comment: @ Mortuza Shahariar: i was trying to fetch data using Gson but it failed. Data is not coming from Gson  in Adapter. How can i get it.

Comment: @AkshaySonavadekar Have a look at my answer if it helps

Answer (score 0):

Ideally your Result.class should be like

```
@SerializedName("items")
ArrayList<Items> itemsList;
.
.
.
your other fields will be here
.
.
.
.
```

then your Items.class should be like

```
@SerializedName("id")
String id;
.
.
.
.
your other fields will be here
.
.
.
.
@SerializedName("product_links")
ArrayList<ProductLinks>productLinksList;
@SerializedName("tier_prices")
ArrayList<TierPrices>tierPricesList;
@SerializedName("custom_attributes")
ArrayList<CustomAttirbutes>customAttributesList;
```

Your problem may be inside Items.class you have used customAttributeList as a String variable instead of ArrayList.

While assigning your volley API response object to your result.class.
Your result object should be exactly map with your volley response object in your case it is miss matching.Which causes to lead this issue.

Comment: I am still not getting data to set on adapter. Is there any way so that I can access data of array of "custom_attributes" in Adapter class i have mentioned above.

Comment: @AkshaySonavadekar please post your result.calss and other model classes under reuslt. class then only i can help by seeing your code... try to edit your question with result.class and other classes under it

Answer (score 0):

According to the **JSON** you provided **value** key does not hold specific object. It's value is depended on the **attribute_code**.

So your **CustomAttribute** class should be like

```
public class CustomAttribute {
    @SerializedName("attribute_code")
    @Expose
    private String attributeCode;
    @SerializedName("value")
    @Expose
    private Object value;
}
```

And than cast your value object according to attributeCode.